# Why do we use backslash to replace a special character in Java?

Tags: java, replace, special-characters, backslash

I wanted to remove  \n  and  \  from my string. First I removed line breakers then I removed backslashes. I couldn't do it in a single step.I did it like below.

> Step 1
>
> ```
>   String query = " \"id\" \\$ \\nVD \\";
>   System.out.println(query);   // "id" \$ \nVD \
> ```
>
> Step2
>
> ```
>   query = query.replaceAll("\\\\n", "");
>   System.out.println(query);   //"id" \$ VD \
> ```
>
> Step 3
>
> ```
>   query = query.replace("\\", "");
>   System.out.println(query);  // "id" $ VD
> ```

In step 2, I have used replaceAll to remove line breakers(\n).

In step 3, I have used replace to remove backslashes from the string. Step 2 was trying to find backslashes with n ie. \n (line breakers) so it avoided the \ (backslashes) alone. I understood that since backslash is a special character we used one more to identify it as literal in the string replace method.

But in step 2, why are we using three backslashes to replace a line breaker?

Answer (score 1):

In step two, you are actually using 4 back (not "black") slashes to replace the `\` and `n` characters.

The `\n`s in your string are not actually new lines. They represent a `\` and a `n` character. To write this in Java code, you need another `\` to escape `\`. So to express `\n` as a string in Java, you need to do:

```
String s = "\\n";
```

Now let's look at `replaceAll`. `replaceAll` takes a regular expression and replaces every match of it in the string. In this case you want to match `\` followed by an `n`. You can't just use a regex like this:

```
\n
```

because `\n` means "to match a new line" in regex. You just want to match `\` and `n`.

So you have to escape the `\` using another `\`. This regex matches a `\` followed by an `n`:

```
\\n
```

Now you got your regex, you need to write it in Java code. You need to express "2 `\`s and an `n`" in a Java string. To do this you need a `\` to escape each `\` in the string. That's why you end up with

```
"\\\\n"
```

The above means `\\n` in regex, which matches `\n` literally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to type them two times because the `String.replaceAll` method takes regex, and in regex the return sign is matched by literal String `\n`. Java syntax escapes the `\n` in string into an single ascii sign. So how would you pass an unchanged `\n` string for the regex? You need to escape it second time, and this results in the double escape backslash -  `\\`, which for `\n` is `\\n`

and in your step2, you don't need `"\\\\n"` you should use `"\\n"`

you need it in step3 instad of `"\\"` you should use `"\\\\"`, bacause without that the regex will see one backslash with no required instruction after that and you will get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
 ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1702)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2223)
    at Test.main(Test.java:33)
```

You can escape both `\` and `"\n"` in one step using this single line (the `|` is like OR in regex)

```
query = query.replaceAll("\\n+|\\\\", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A character preceded by a backslash (\) is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler.
```

from this [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)